# In Power BI, how can I create a column that changes based on a slicer and visualization?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm pretty new to Power BI. I'm unsure how to approach this.

I have one visualization that displays the ten most frequently bought products in a time frame that is set by a slicer. In another visualization, I display how those products have been selling over the past few years (this time frame is not determined by the slicer). I want to display only the ten products that come from the first visualization, not the ten most common over the time frame in the second visualization.

How can I accomplish this? The approach I have in mind (and I'm open to others) is to create a true/false column that changes with the first visualization. "True" would be for products that are frequently bought as determined by the first visualization in the slicer-determined time range, and the second visualization would only look at values with a "true" in that column. How can I create a column (or table, maybe?) that changes depending on a visualization?

Comment: You can't use this approach - calculated columns don't respond to visualizations or slicers. I recommend to re-write the question, with a data sample, data model diagram image, and an example of the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Clarification: most of the pages will say Top10 ... Actually, the measure used was a simple Top5 that includes products with the same number of orders than the 5th product. Therefore, to avoid dealing with larger images, 7 products will be seen but it is a Top5 ranking. The idea is you can replace it with your custom TopN measure.

What I understood:

The simplification of your model plus the disconnected help table would be:

[image]

> I have one visualization that displays the ten most frequently bought
> products in a time frame that is set by a slicer.

[image]

- The Date slicer belongs to the Dates table in the Data model.
- The table viz represents the number of rows in the sales table in the
  current context (for each product within the Date range).
- The table viz is sorted according to the [#Rows] measure in descending
  order.
- The table viz only presents the TopN products even without the presence
  of the [#Rows] measure due to the presence of the [TopOrders]
  measure within *Filters on this visual*. **[TopOrders] is 1**.

On the second page you create:

- A slicer with the Dates[Date] column (the same one used on the
  previous page).
- A matrix with Products[ProductName] on the rows, HDates[Year] on
  the columns, and a measure on values.

From the View tab, you select the Sync Slicers option.

Inside the Sync Slicers pane:

- In the Sync column, check the boxes related to the necessary pages.
- In the Display column uncheck the box that contains the over
  years report.

[image]

So far all we have done is pass the time frame context from page 1 to page 2.

Since the TopN context depends on the time frame context, we can now use the [TopOrders] measure as a *Filters on this visual* in the matrix. Again, **[TopOrders] is 1**.

[image]

Why do the numbers differ between rows and not between columns?

*Also, in this example, the Sales table only has information up to 12/31/2020 but the visualization shows an additional year and the Sales[Amount] values for each order is $1 so that [#Orders] and [SalesAmount] are the same for easy comparison.*

HDates is not related to the model and for each combination of HDates[Year]-Products[ProductName], the [SalesAmount] measure is using the information coming from the previously hidden slicer and the respective Products[ProductName] because the information coming from HDates[Year] has no effect yet.

In order to complete this exercise, it only remains to modify the [SalesAmount] measure in such a way that it removes the filter on the time frame (Dates[Date]) and it recognizes HDates[Year] as Dates[Year].

```
SalesAmount := 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Sales[Amount]),
    ALL(Dates),
    TREATAS(VALUES(HDates[Year]),Dates[Year])
    )
```

And this is the final result.

[image]

I hope it works for someone or the idea can be improved.